# Position image above or below text relatively.

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a pretty absurd question but has been bugging me for a while now. I am designing this [website](http://drleilamasson.com) and I am just finishing off on the responsive/mobile view. Currently it looks okay but that's because I delete the images with `display : none:` when the view port becomes too small for the image to look good. (Can bee seen at `drleilamasson.com/css/responsive.css`)

The images I want to change are the book (under the book section) and the parrot (under the social section) If I were to not delete them they would just go over the text / embedded post I have and block the content. What I want to happen is that the **book image goes above the text centered perfectly**. I have fiddled around with the styles of these images but never been able to figure it out.

I hope you guys can figure it out! Thanks :)

Comment: What are the ids/classes of the 2 images? That is a lot of css.

Comment: @Popatop15 Check the inspector. Im out now but I think it's leila-book-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already set a flexbox parent on the `<section id="about">`, so we can play with the direction and ordering of the children.

```
@media (max-width: 1065px) {
  #about {
    flex-direction: column; /* stack the children */
  }

  .leila-book-img {
    ...
    display: none; <-- remove
    margin: 0 auto;
    order: 2; /* put the image container after the text */
  }

  .about-content {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thankyou! Exactly what I wanted. I'll check it out when I get back to the office.

Comment: Just wondering, are all my sections flexbox? I've never heard of flexbox before, do you maybe know of a tutorial? Thanks!!!

Comment: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is currently the best *supported* way we can control layout in ways which were previously impossible. It's supported in all modern browsers as well as IE10+. I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like `#about` may be the only `<section>` on your website using flexbox.

Comment: Well, it's no accident. Your developer must have coded it that way.